# Dynamically adjust height of first child div based on height of second child div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div and two child divs. The second child div is variable height, but is absolutely positioned at the bottom of the parent div.

I want the first div to have a dynamic height based on the second div. I thought `margin-bottom: 10px` would specify the height of the first div to go up until 10px of the second div, but apparently this is not true.

Is there any workaround to get what I want?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
     Hello
  </div>
  <div class="second" >
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.first {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.second {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4tjqsron/2/

Answer (score 0):

The margin-bottom is only telling the browser "don't let anything come within 10px of the bottom of me," as you found out.

I think this may be an excellent opportunity to use the `calc()` css function!

Try this:

```
.first {
     background-color: green;
     height: calc(100% - 110px);
}
```

This should leave a 10px space between your first and second child element.
Basically it is telling the browser that the first element is to take up 100% of its parent minus 110px.
Please see this for more info on the calc() function.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp
I hope this helps!

EDIT: It just occurred to me that this only works if your height is set elsewhere. You may need to adjust your use of the 100% argument depending on your current parent height settings. Even if this is the case, the calc() function should still prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not get your point very clearly, here is my solution that `div.second` will always align on the bottom of `div.parent` vertically:

```css
.parent {
  height: 500px;
  min-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.first {
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.second {
/*   height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; */
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
     Hello
  </div>
  <div class="second" >No matter how many content in this div, it will always lie on the bottom of the parent div</div>
</div>
```